# How to resolve the Java and SQL Express connection error

Tags: java, sql-server

The error is

> **Sql exception com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using
>   Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error:
>   "sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target".
>   ClientConnectionId:1be09c56-25db-4f1c-9703-1bb9802ed0b0**

My Code is :

```
private void btn_loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String url = url="jdbc:sqlserver://PRATHAM-PC\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;authentication=SqlPassword;databaseName=SaleMNG;user=sa;password=hutch&idea"; 
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        System.out.println("connection created");
        Statement st=conn.createStatement();
        String sql="select * from UserLogin";
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println("Name: "+rs.getString(1));
            //System.out.println("Address : "+rs.getString(2));
        }
        if(st!=null)
        st.close();
        if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException sqle)
    {
        System.out.println("Sql exception "+sqle);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2016/11/30/intermittent-jdbc-connectivity-issue-the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-sql-server-by-using-secure-sockets-layer-ssl-encryption-error-sql-server-returned-an-incomplete-respons/)

Comment: I was facing a similar kind of problem few days back regd the certificate one not the microsoft db one, the error means that you don't have a valid certificate to the site/ server that you/ the java application is accessing! Identify the certificate that you are missing and then add that valid certificate to your Java keystore which would then make it work.  This link describes it the best: https://www.paypal.com/sg/selfhelp/article/how-do-i-update-my-java-cacerts-keystore-ts1494 Let me know if that worked for you...

Comment: I followed all the steps and they finished successful but found same error again